# What is the impact or change in user experience from the New Contributor label?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, user-interface

I have always tried to take into consideration of the user's reputation score when providing comments or feedback to their questions or answers.

The introduction of the "New Contributor" tag explicitly calls this out to all the users, and was an attempt to help improve the user experience for people who are contributing content for the first time. This was also introduced as part of the New Code of Conduct.

Does anyone have either anecdotal or stats supporting that this has actually helped to improve the user experience for newcomers? This could be just for UXSE or any StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

In this era of unfettered cyber bullying and non-provoked verbal and textual violence, small checks n' measures and notifiers like the **New Contributor** label is a welcome addition to the community.

I don't have any stats as such, but personally, I feel like the comments on new posts have become a lot more calm. It helps understand the intention and the possible misunderstanding of the contributor.

Two thumbs up for this addition.